# web service vs server program for android location awareness app

Tags: android

I am making a small android app, that can show other users' location. I need to make a server/web service which gets the location of all the users and broadcast to all the users.   For such purpose, should i use web service or make a dedicated socket server program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either will work fine. A web service has more overhead so if you are looking for the most network and server resource efficient way possible, you can use server sockets.